# Adding data from the second table to the first matching record in first table and setting the rest to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I’m trying to join two tables in SQL Server as below:
(these are sample tables and the actual one has thousands of records)

- Sales table

| ID | SALESID | ITEM | Details… |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | Item1 |  |
| 2 | S1 | Item2 |  |
| 3 | S1 | Item3 |  |
| 4 | S2 | Item 4 |  |
| 5 | S3 | Item 5 |  |
| 6 | S3 | Item 6 |  |

- Invoice table

| INVSALESID | Invoice amount |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | A |
| S2 | B |
| S3 | C |
| S4 | D |
| S5 | E |
| S6 | F |

I’m hoping to get the invoice amount added to the first record and rest as 0 to avoid duplication when I am taking the sum for further analysis.

Current result:

```
Select s.*,Invoice_amount 

FROM Sales_table s
join Invoice_table inv on  s.salesid=inv.InvSalesId
where s.ID = (
       select top 1 s.ID  FROM Sales_table s1
       WHERE S.SALESID=S1.SALESID
          
      )
```

| ID | SALESID | ITEM | Invoice amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | Item1 | A |
| 2 | S1 | Item2 | A |
| 3 | S1 | Item3 | A |
| 4 | S2 | Item 4 | B |
| 5 | S3 | Item 5 | C |
| 6 | S3 | Item 6 | C |

Expected result:

| ID | SALESID | ITEM | Invoice amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | Item1 | A |
| 2 | S1 | Item2 | 0 |
| 3 | S1 | Item3 | 0 |
| 4 | S2 | Item 4 | B |
| 5 | S3 | Item 5 | C |
| 6 | S3 | Item 6 | 0 |

Comment: What is your current attempt that returns the data you are getting? You forgot to include it.

Comment: Hi @ThomA, oh yes! It should be updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
select id, SALESID, item, [Details…], case when row_number() over(partition by salesid order by id) = 1 then [invoice amount] else 0 end
from (
    VALUES  (1, N'S1', N'Item1', NULL)
    ,   (2, N'S1', N'Item2', NULL)
    ,   (3, N'S1', N'Item3', NULL)
    ,   (4, N'S2', N'Item 4', NULL)
    ,   (5, N'S3', N'Item 5', NULL)
    ,   (6, N'S3', N'Item 6', NULL)
) t (ID,SALESID,ITEM,[Details…])
inner join (
    VALUES  (N'S1', 10)
    ,   (N'S2', 20)
    ,   (N'S3', 30)
    ,   (N'S4', 40)
    ,   (N'S5', 50)
    ,   (N'S6', 60)
) t2 (NVSALESID,[Invoice amount])
    ON  t2.nvsalesid = t.SALESID
```

you partition by salesid and check if it's first row then return amount, otherwise 0